# Turn several ajax requests into Observables with RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm struggling with something - which I'm guessing means I've misunderstood and am doing something silly

I have an observable and need to use it to create some object, send that to the server for processing, combine a result from the server with the object I sent, and then turn that into an observable so what I want to do (I think) is something like

```
var theNewObservable = my.observable.things.select(function(thing) {
            var dataToSend = generateMyJavascriptObjectFrom(thing);
            var promise = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: http://somewhere.com,
                data: dataToSend
            }).promise();

            return rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise).subscribe(function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                var infoFromServer = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('custom-header-returned');
                    // I'm wanting this to be the thing other code can subscribe to
                return { infoFromServer: dataToSend };
            }, function(err) {
                alert('PC LOAD LETTER!');
                console.error(err);
            });
        }
});

theNewObservable.subscribe(function(combinedInfo) { console.log(combinedInfo) };
```

where I'm expecting `{infoFromServer: dataToSend}` I'm getting an `AutoDetachObserver` and I can see that has an onNext with the ajax onSuccess signature so I'm obviously doing something silly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things that should help a bit:

1) The `subscribe` method is a terminal method, as in, it won't return anything. It is where the `Observer` attaches so there should be no further data propagation after the `subscribe`

2) The `onNext` method of `subscribe` can only take a single value which you will need to have all the message data wrapped in.

Since jQuery's `Promise` will not behave well with this, you have two options. First, you can use the [RX-DOM](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM) project for an `Observable` ajax version. Or you will need to wrap the promise method. If you further need to wait on the response you should be using `selectMany` instead, which will allow you to fire off the promise, then await its return and map the response to the original request.

```
var theNewObservable = my.observable.things
          //Preprocess this so that `selectMany` will use 
          //dataToSend as the request object
          .map(function(thing) { return generateMyJavascriptObjectFrom(thing); })
          .selectMany(function(dataToSend) {
            var promise = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: http://somewhere.com,
                data: dataToSend
            }).promise();

            //Rewrap this into a promise that RxJS can handle
            return promise.then(function(data, status, jqXHR) {
              return {data : data, status : status, jqXHR : jqXHR};
            });
          }, function(request, response) {
            return {
                    infoFromServer : response.jqXHR.getResponse('custom-header'),
                    dataToSend : request
                   };
          });

theNewObservable.subscribe(
  function(combinedInfo) { 
    console.log(combinedInfo) 
  },
  function(err) {
    alert('PC LOAD LETTER!');
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Comment: thanks, that's really useful - there's lots to get my head around in RxJS :) I control the server too so to keep myself moving I'm bouncing the `dataToSend` back in the response to avoid the need to keep hold of it. But I'll set up a spike so I can understand how your answer works...